# Recycler list stucks allot while scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have added simple v7.widget.RecyclerView and set the adapter simply but while scrolling the list it jerks allot, scrolling is not working out smoothly. Infact I used few library as well for fast scrolling but nothing works. I have picasso inside adapter to load images while data setting or handling visibility is done in "onBindViewHolder".
If someone have better solution than kindly help me out.

I already tried all the below methods but none of them works

```
@BindView(R.id.rv_list)
RecyclerView rvList;

ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(rvList, false);

rvList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
rvList.setHasFixedSize(true);
rvList.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
rvList.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);                     
rvList.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
```

Below is my Adapter Code:

```
            public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<cadapter.RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

                Context ctx;
                ArrayList<Model> Modelslist;

                GlobalClass gc;

                View itemView;
                View parentView;
                private RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerAdapterListener listener;
                PrefManager prefManager;

                public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> Modelslist, RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerAdapterListener listener) {

                    this.Modelslist = Modelslist;
                    this.ctx = context;
                    gc = GlobalClass.getInstance();
                    this.listener = listener;
                    prefManager = new PrefManager(context);
                }

                @Override
                public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                    return position;
                }

                @Override
                public long getItemId(int position) {
                    return position;
                }


                @Override
                public RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);

                    if (itemView == null) {
                        parentView = new RelativeLayout(this.ctx);
                    } else {
                        parentView = (RelativeLayout) itemView;
                    }
                    return new RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

                    final Model cat = this.Modelslist.get(position);

                    holder.txtNumber.setText(cat.getNumber());
                    holder.txtName.setText(cat.getName());

                    final String flagPath = cat.getFlag();

                    if(cat.getForwarding1().equals("0")) {
                        holder.callForwardingSwitch.setChecked(true);


                        holder.txtCallRateVal.setText(cat.getForwardingCost());

                        holder.txtCallRateVal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.txtCallRate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.txtCallRateVal2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.txtCallRateVal2.setTextColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.text_grey));

                        ////VISIBLE call Forwading Text
                        holder.txtCallRateVal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.txtCallRate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else{
                        holder.callForwardingSwitch.setChecked(false);

                        ////Hide call Forwading Text
                        holder.txtCallRateVal.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.txtCallRate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.txtCallRateVal2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                    holder.txtNumberDesc.setText(cat.getDetails());
                    holder.txtRenewDate.setText(cat.getrenewal_date());
                    holder.txtSetupVal.setText(cat.getcost());
                    holder.txtMonthlyVal.setText(cat.getmonthlycost());

                    String application_status= cat.getapplication_status();
                    System.out.println("Application status:::::: "+ application_status+" number: "+cat.getNumber());
                    if(application_status.equals("0")){
                        holder.txtStatus.setText("* Pending Approval");
                        holder.txtStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        holder.txtStatus.setTextColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.account_error));

                        holder.txtCallRateVal.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.txtCallRateVal2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        holder.txtCallRate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        ////////Unclicking Highlight Delete and call Forwarding
                        holder.Delete.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.number_delete_gray);
                        holder.Delete.setClickable(false);

                        holder.callForwardingSwitch.setChecked(false);
                        holder.callForwardingSwitch.setClickable(false);
                        // holder.callForwardingSwitch.setHighlightColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.text_dark_grey));
                        /////////Visible Tag
                        holder.rel__number_status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.rel__number_status.setBackground(ctx.getDrawable(R.drawable._submitted_tag));
                        holder.txtNumberStatus.setText("Registration Submitted *");

                        /////// Hide Renew Date:
                        holder.txtRenew.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.txtRenewDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }else  if(application_status.equals("1")){
                        holder.txtStatus.setText("Click here to complete number registration");
                        holder.txtStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        /////////Visible Tag
                        holder.rel__number_status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.rel__number_status.setBackground(ctx.getDrawable(R.drawable._saved_tag));
                        holder.txtNumberStatus.setText("Registration Incomplete");

                        /////// Hide Renew Date:
                        holder.txtRenew.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.txtRenewDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        holder.txtStatus.setTextColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.app_header));
                    }else  if(application_status.equals("2")){//////Approved///
                        //holder.txtStatus.setText("Approved");

                        holder.txtStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.txtStatus.setText("Active");
                        holder.txtStatus.setTextColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.green600));

                        /////////Hide Tag
                        holder.rel__number_status.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        holder.txtSetupVal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.txtSetup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        /////// VISIBLE Renew Date:
                        holder.txtRenew.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.txtRenewDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else  if(application_status.equals("3")){///// Rejected///
                        //holder.txtStatus.setText("Rejected");

                        /////////Hide Tag
                        holder.txtStatus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.rel__number_status.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        /////// VISIBLE Renew Date:
                        holder.txtRenew.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.txtRenewDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }else{
                        if(cat.getLocal().equals("1") && cat.getAddress().equals("1")
                                && cat.getPhoto().equals("1") && cat.getapplication_status().equals("-1")){
                            holder.txtStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.txtStatus.setText("Active");
                            holder.txtStatus.setTextColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.green600));
                            holder.rel__number_status.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                            holder.txtSetupVal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.txtSetup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }else{
                            holder.txtStatus.setText("");
                            /////////Hide Tag
                            holder.txtStatus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            holder.rel__number_status.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println("Flag::::::::::: "+ flagPath);
                        /*Picasso.with(ctx)
                                .load(flagPath) // thumbnail url goes here
                                .into(holder.CountryFlagim, new Callback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess() {
                                        Picasso.with(ctx)
                                                .load(flagPath) // image url goes here
                                                .placeholder(holder.CountryFlagim.getDrawable())
                                                .into(holder.CountryFlagim);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError() {

                                    }
                                });*/
                    Glide
                            .with(ctx)
                            .load(flagPath)
                            .centerCrop()
                            .placeholder(holder.CountryFlagim.getDrawable())
                            .into(holder.CountryFlagim);
                    //Picasso.with(ctx).load(flagPath).into(holder.CountryFlagim);


                    applyClickEvents(holder,position);


                }


                @Override
                public int getItemCount() {
                    if (this.Modelslist != null) {
                        return this.Modelslist.size();
                    } else {
                        return 0;
                    }

                }

                private void applyClickEvents(final RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

                    holder.mainFrame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            listener.moveToDetailScreen(position);
                        }
                    });

                    holder.Delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            final Model cat = Modelslist.get(position);

                        }
                    });


                    holder.callForwardingSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                            System.out.println("Call forwarding switch: "+ b);

                        }
                    });

                }


                public interface NumberListAdapterListener {

                    void deleteItem(int position);
                    void moveToDetailScreen(int position);

                }

                public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                    RelativeLayout rel__number,rel__setup,rel__number_status;
                    ImageView CountryFlagim;
                    TextView txtNumber, txtName;
                    SwitchCompat callForwardingSwitch;
                    TextView txtNumberDesc;
                    TextView txtSetupVal, txtSetup;
                    TextView txtMonthlyVal;
                    TextView txtCallRateVal, txtCallRateVal2, txtCallRate;
                    TextView txtStatus;
                    TextView txtNumberStatus, txtRenewDate, txtRenew;
                    Button Delete;
                    RelativeLayout mainFrame;


                    public MyViewHolder(View v) {
                        super(v);

                        rel__number = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.rel__number);
                        rel__setup = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.rel__setup);
                        rel__number_status = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.rel__number_status);
                        CountryFlagim = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.CountryFlagim);
                        txtNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
                        txtName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtName);

                        txtNumberDesc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtNumberDesc);
                        txtSetupVal = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtSetupVal);
                        txtSetup = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtSetup);

                        txtMonthlyVal = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtMonthlyVal);
                        txtCallRate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtCallRate);
                        txtCallRateVal = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtCallRateVal);
                        txtCallRateVal2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtCallRateVal2) ;
                        txtStatus = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
                        txtNumberStatus = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtNumberStatus);
                        Delete = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Delete);
                        callForwardingSwitch = (SwitchCompat) v.findViewById(R.id.callForwardingSwitch);
                        mainFrame = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.mainFrame);
                        txtRenewDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtRenewDate);
                        txtRenew = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtRenew);

                    }
                }






            }
```

Comment: can you post code of Adapter ?

Comment: What SDK version are you on?

Comment: @RyanGodlonton-Shaw I am using SDK version 28

Comment: That should work fine. Have you tried other devices?

Comment: @MayurRaval I have added Adapter code above.

Comment: @RyanGodlonton-Shaw I tried Nokia and motorola device having nougat and oreo still facing same issue.

Comment: If Images are thumbnail then try to reduce image size like 

`Glide.with(ctx).load(flagPath).override(100,100).centerCrop()           .placeholder(holder.CountryFlagim.getDrawable())                           .into(holder.CountryFlagim);`

Let me know outcome

Comment: And there are lots of if-else please try to reduce that if possible. it is good if you try to manage if-else condition out of list means before setting it to list.

one more thing have you used Coordinator layout in your list view item row ?

Comment: @MayurRaval after adding override in Glide and removed all the if-else conditions and set the temporary data but it still not working fine.

Comment: @MayurRaval Nope I din't used Coordinator layout in list view item row

Comment: Can you please avoid Relative layout in xml ? instead use frame layout or linear layout if possible

Comment: One more thing you can do. Just use Android profiler for stack trace what are big things happen in background while scrolling. you can get exact root cause from there

Comment: @MayurRaval as you suggested about Linear layout I tried but still facing the same issue, while I saw Android profiler for stack trace it shows a static(Linear) flow no ups or downs of memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Glide. Glide doesn't load full size picture and uses less memory, which should be faster than Picasso.

Comment: I tried Glide but still the issue is same infact I tested scroll by removing Picasso/Glide but still facing same issue. So I don't think that issue is due to picasso or Glide or setting image in a row.